# How to run trigger separate of table

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, triggers

I have a trigger as shown below:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[areftblSalesDoc] ON [dbo].[tblSalesDoc]
AFTER INSERT
AS
Begin Try
    INSERT INTO ArefSms
        (DSIDName, SalesID, CustName, CustCellPhone, Fish, qt, ProdName)
    SELECT
        td.DSName, i.SalesID, tc.CustName, tc.CustCellPhone, i.Fish, NULL, NULL
        FROM inserted i
        left join tblDistributionStationDesc td on i.DSID = td.DSID
        left join tblCustomerDesc tc on i.CustomerID = tc.CustID

End Try
Begin Catch

End catch
```

When trigger can't save anything and has error `tblsalesdoc` can't save too. But I don't want that.

What can I do?

Comment: What?!?!? Please explain - this is absolutely unclear - ***what*** do you want to do? "Regular" triggers are **always** attached to a table (unless you're talking about DDL triggers, which record things like `CREATE TABLE` and so forth)

Comment: What is your Question. Please rephrase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to skip trigger code in case of error, You can try to use [SAVE TRANSACTION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188378.aspx) statement

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[areftblSalesDoc] ON [dbo].[tblSalesDoc]
AFTER INSERT
AS

SAVE TRANSACTION BeforeInsertInTrigger;

Begin Try
    INSERT INTO ArefSms
        (DSIDName, SalesID, CustName, CustCellPhone, Fish, qt, ProdName)
    SELECT
        td.DSName, i.SalesID, tc.CustName, tc.CustCellPhone, i.Fish, NULL, NULL
        FROM inserted i
        left join tblDistributionStationDesc td on i.DSID = td.DSID
        left join tblCustomerDesc tc on i.CustomerID = tc.CustID

End Try
Begin Catch
   ROLLBACK TRANSACTION BeforeInsertInTrigger;
   RETURN
End catch
```